# Проблема с url в стилях

Tags: css, wordpress, url

Есть чужой сайт на WordPress, к которому я пишу тему. Структура темы "my_theme" следующая:

```
\css
   main.css
\script
   main.js
\img
   some_img.png
index.php
```

Тема лежит, как и полагается, в "**my_domain/wp-content/themes/my_theme**".
Пути к скриптам и стилям подключены в functions.php и прекрасно работают.
functions.php:

`define('CSS_DIR', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style');`

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style_main', CSS_DIR . '/main.css' );
});`

Проблема:
 почему то пути в стилях прописанные как url(../img/some_img.png) ссылаются не на
"**my_domain/wp-content/themes/my_theme/img/some_img.png**"
а на
"**my_domain/img/some_img.png**"

В чем причины? Может, настройки сервера? Постоянные ссылки? Даже не знаю, в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: А как вы стили подключаете?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Добавил описания подключения стилей в главном посте.

Answer (score 2):

Пути в стилях должны быть прописаны от корня сайта:

не `url(../img/some_img.png)`

a `url(/wp-content/themes/my_theme/img/some_img.png)`

Comment: Я думал об этом, но это выглядит как костыль и мой внутренний перфекционист ругал меня за это. Ну если более элегантного решения нет, делать нечего. Спасибо.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, а вот тут https://brobank.ru/credit-card-tinkoff-platinum/ вот так:  https://i.imgur.com/6zDNu1S.jpg. ;) Я сильно не вникал как так получается, но с кандача не понял как так получилось (пару дней назад увидел). По логике должно ж быть от корня сайта. И так оно и получается если повторить. А почему так получатся на этом сайте - я так и  не понял (но и не сильно разбирался - руки не дошли ибо не особо и нужно. Хотя интересно)

Comment: @SeVlad на самом деле относительгные ссылки работают. Их полно везде: и в ядре, и в плагинах (jetpack), и в темах (storefront). Я так ответил, предполагая, что у автора некая ошибка в размещении файлов стилей, а информации, чтобы её отловить, недостаточно.

Comment: @KAGGDesign как? Я тогда от удивления попробовал повторить то что у видел и у меня не получилось. Т.е. получилось ровно так как и должно было получиться - урл картинки получался относительно поста (точнее урла - site.ru/post_name/image/img.jpg), а не от темы.

Comment: @SeVlad а я попробовал на пустой теме, созданной с нуля - и получилось. Интересная штука выходит - иногда относительные ссылки не работают, и мы не понимаем, почему. Но тогда и storefront не должна работать, однако.

Comment: @KAGGDesign (я поправил пред. коммент) Относительные - на то ж и относительные, что бы работали относительно запрашиваемого урла. А почему на указанном сайте работает относительно темы - вот тут загадка. //Про storefront не понял - там вообще нет картинок в стилях.//